# Error: TSortedMap with a custom struct as key, overloading operator<

Tags: struct, unreal-engine4

I am trying to implement a [TSortedMap](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TSortedMap/index.html) with my custom struct as the key. I have overloaded the operators for the struct. However, when I try to compile I get this error at the line of code where I am adding an element to the TSortedMap:

```
error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const T'
(or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

My struct:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FUtility
{
GENERATED_BODY()

public:

UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, meta=(ClampMin = "0.0", ClampMax = "1.0"))
float value = 0.0f;

UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, meta = (ClampMin = "0.0", ClampMax = "1.0"))
float weight = 1.0f;

FORCEINLINE bool operator== (const FUtility& other)
{
    return this->value == other.value && this->weight == other.weight;
}

FORCEINLINE bool operator< (const FUtility& other)
{
    return (this->value * this->weight) < (other.value * other.weight);
}

.....

friend uint32 GetTypeHash(const FUtility& other)
{
    return GetTypeHash(other.value) + GetTypeHash(other.weight);
}
};
```

Not quite sure why it is not compiling since it is overloaded. Maybe it isn't overloaded correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, oddly enough I figured it out. It was really bugging me that all of the operator logic in the documentation took two parameters. It turns out I was just missing the `friend` keyword. From there I was able to add the second parameter and it compiled nicely.

Example:

```
friend bool operator< (const FUtility& a, const FUtility& b)
{
    return (a.value * a.weight) < (b.value * b.weight);
}
```